# Share Mac App without Mac App store

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

How to share mac desktop application on mountain lion to limited user without using Mac App store?
Can anyone tell me the procedure?
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Upload to cloud(Dropbox, Sugarsync,IDrive,crashPlane) and share.

Comment: Use the Finder to compress the file into a .zip file.   At that point, it's just like any file and you can share it through any mechanism you like (such as suggested by @ParagBafna).

Answer (score 0):

1. Compress your application in finder.
2. Upload to cloud([Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/), [Sugarsync](https://www.sugarsync.com),[IDrive](https://www.idrive.com/index.html),[crashPlane](http://www.crashplan.com/)) and share.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

1) In the Apple Developer Portal, under "Certificates and Identifiers" ensure that your developers (and their Mac UUID's are all added to the portal
2) Download their corresponding profiles and make sure that they're installed on their development mac's (the ones which you registered under devices)
3) In Xcode, when you build an app for development testing, make sure that you're code-signing as "Mac Developer"

Once this is done, check that it's code-signed properly by dropping to terminal and testing it (this example I'll check the Apple Mail app):

```
04:31 $ spctl -vvvv -a  /Applications/Mail.app
/Applications/Mail.app: accepted
source=Apple System
origin=Software Signing
```

If that passed, then it's free to distribute to your development team. In this case, it's not a developer app, but in the case of a developer app it'll appear as:

```
04:34 $ spctl -vvvv -a ./SomeApp.app
./SomeApp.app: accepted
source=Mac Developer
origin=Mac Developer: Your Details (TEAMID12345)
```

From here you can zip it up and email it to your development team to run on their machines.